# I got something for you. "Got" means "brought" or " have- possession"

Tags: grammar

When watching US movies, I often hear something like this:

> A: I got something for you.
>
> *(Then A gives B a present he bought for her)*
>
> B: Thank you so much.

I don't know what the meaning of "got", I think that "got" here has one out of the two meanings below, but I don't know which one:

1."Got" is the past tense of "get".

I **got** something for you= I **bought** something for you.

2.I know that in the US, "got" sometimes means "have" :

I **got** something for you= I **have** something for you.

Comment: I CV'd because it's impossible to know which meaning is intended without more context. I'll just note that in the U.S. "I've got" would be more common (though not mandatory) for the second meaning.

Comment: I mainly agree with @MarcInManhattan but 'I got' is more likely to mean 'I acquired' whereas 'I've got' is more likely 'I have in my possession'. Neither is set in stone though.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan what is the meaning of “CV’d”?

Comment: Marcin has explained why they voted to close, i.e *Close Voted* (CV'd), the question.

Comment: What @MarcInManhattan said. The text is inherently ambiguous, and I don't see the point in speculating as to which parsing is most *likely* to apply. But sense #1 can be unambiguously conveyed simply by switching to an explicitly ditransitive verb usage without preposition: *I **got you** something*.

Comment: In the US, **have got** is shortened to **got** but that's only in non-standard lingo., But in the UK, you might also hear: Got the money or not? Also, a shortening of have got. got=bought, obtained, purchased, received.

Answer (score 3):

**To get something for someone**, means **to obtain/procure something for someone**. It doesn't mean **bought** or **have** in the example.

Use of **got** here doesn't specify how the gift was actually procured. It could have been bought, but we'd only know this from the context, for example, if we saw him buy it in a shop, or if somebody mentioned that he'd bought it. If there was no context given, there could be many possible scenarios: e.g., He could have stolen it for her, he could have found it for her, he could have made it for her, etc, etc. There are many ways to obtain/procure something.

This is a fairly common construction used in informal/colloquial English and is not just US specific. As far as I know, all English speakers either use this, or are at least familiar with it.

Comment: Agreed - "I got" is completely transpondian; though "gotten" is left bank only ;)

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I wouldn't be so sure of that - the word "gotten" came from Britain originally, but went out of fashion in standard English, but that doesn't mean that English speakers in the UK suddenly stopped using it.  There are some regions/dialects where it survived, Scotland being one of them. Google this "he has gotten a gentle wife".

Comment: The most logical assumption in that scene is the speaker purchased a birthday gift. If it was handmade they would have said "I made this for you. I hope you like it”

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes in this particular context, but using "got" in this way doesn't specifically mean "bought". That would be a context driven assumption.

Comment: Yes, it does mean to buy or purchase here. I obtained something for you. to buy and that's how English speakers use it. In the US and in the UK etc. "I got something for you" [today, at the shops, online etc. etc. etc/] is the past tense of get.

Comment: @Lambie - it only does here, in this specific example, because the context is mentioned by the OP. However, the word "got" does not mean "bought" - it only means obtained/procured. Without any context, I could say "I got some flowers for you today". That wouldn't rule out the possibility that I picked them from my garden, or stole them from a graveyard.

Comment: Yes, it does in many context; Did you get the butter at the supermarket or street fair? Yes, it does not only mean bought but often does mean it: bought, purchased, received, obtained, became [rich etc.], understand, etc.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. It's only the context that gives it that meaning.

Comment: The OP clearly specifies the context **(Then A gives B a present he bought for her)**. There is no ambiguity, there is no "we don't know how the speaker obtained it“. Yes, we do.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I didn't say "we don't know how the speaker obtained it".   I said "If there was no context given".

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of *got* in “I got something for you” could either be:

a. I **have got** something for someone.
b. I **bought** or **obtained** something for someone.

The contracted form **I've got** is also used in informal speech.

The following all mean the same as “**Joe bought tickets** to the concert”

1. Joe **got** tickets to the concert. (informal)
2. Joe **has got** tickets to the concert. (BrEng and AmEng)
3. Joe'**s got** tickets… (contracted form)
4. Joe **has gotten** tickets … (AmEng, informal)

Comment: "I got some wine while shopping". I bought. And this is not have got as in have in hand. 
"Has he got the wine now?". To have in hand.

Comment: If B hear the sentence ""I got you something" from A. B won't know if A mean the sentence a (have got-in possession )  or sentence b (bought or obtained) . Am I right?

Comment: @LEHANH  If a friend tells me, "I have **got** something **for** ***you***” my immediate response will be, "What?" Because if it's not my birthday or an anniversary of some sorts, then that "something" could be anything.  No one just goes up to a friend or partner and utters this line without some sort of context. Maybe that "something" is a document, an exam result, my lost pair of sunglasses. It could be anything, I won't know if it was purchased until I *get* = receive the object.

Comment: I will provide the context like this: I found that my friend have been sad recently. I decided to buy a gift for her to surprise and make her happy again. Now, I meet her in our class. I say to her: How are you? Hey, I got something for you. My friend: Thank you so much.// If my friend hears this sentence "I got something for you", she won't know if I used "got" to mean "have- in possession now" or "acquired/ obtained".

Comment: You said so enough, you bought your friend a gift, the gift will look new not old. Your friend will **see** what it is you bought for her. I have something **for you** = strongly suggests that you are **giving** an item to someone.  1. **She's got a new car** What do you think it means? Maybe she bought it, maybe their parents bought them a new car, or maybe not. That is  information which we will have to find out, but she **now possesses** a new car. If someone **gets a parking fine**, what does that mean? It means they received a parking ticket.  (fine).

Comment: Does these 3 sentences have the same meaning that she currently own a new car at the present moment  1. "She has got a new car now"? 2. "She got a new car now" 3."She has a new car now"

Comment: @LEHANH A few corrections:   **Do** these 3 sentences mean the same, that she currently **owns** a new car at the present moment **?** Yes but  No.2 is very informal, I'd say **She's got**… All the examples are listed in my answer. It's true that Joe could have bought or received the tickets but in real life we would say if Joe received the tickets as a gift, if he had won the tickets, even if he had found them lying on the sidewalk/pavement. In Joe's context, "get" means obtain, and usually that means someone *bought* the tickets.

Comment: I would like to change the context and the sentence to make thing easy for me to understand. "I got a new car. That is a new modal. Would you like to try?" There are two ways to understand the "got": (1) "got" is past tense of "get", it generally means "obtained/ acquired" (2) "got" means "have/have got/in possession" in  a very informal way to speak as you said. When my friend hears this sentence, he doesn't know if I am using which meaning of "got". It is only me who know which actually the meaning of "got" here.

Comment: Comments should be reserved for clarification not for asking new, albeit, related questions.